# Year to Century Codewars task

Tags: python, function, if-statement, math

> The first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second century - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200, etc.

Task
Given a year, return the century it is in.

```
def century(year):
    # Finish this :)
    if year % 10 == 0:
        return (year // 100)
    else:
        return (year // 100) +1
print(century(8110))
```

For some reason that I don't understand, some of random tests to this task fail. Some specific numbers such as 6580,3150,2560,8030,8460 are not passing the test cases. Could you explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Why would you treat years differently `if year % 10 == 0:`? What would be the difference between 2020 and 2022?

Comment: Probably, the `% 10` should be `% 100`?

Answer (score 1):

Your program returns an incorrect answer for inputs that are multiples of 10, but not 100. (e.g. your program says that `2009` and `2011` are in the 21st century, but `2010` is in the 20th century.)

You should only avoid adding one to the century count if a year is a multiple of *100*, not 10.

```py
def century(year):
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return (year // 100)
    else:
        return (year // 100) +1
```